# How to implement global.asax in Umbraco 4.8

Tags: umbraco

We have used Umbraco  4.8 as a CMS for application development.  When any error occurs in application it need to redirect to tech error page, and we need to log the error in database. So that we are trying to do with application_error event in `global.asax', but unable to add global.asax and application_error in umbraco.

Is there any way to add `global.asax` or application_error event in Umbraco 4.8?

please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks,

fazalu.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class corHandleErrors : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected override void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Should do the trick